# Pixels from top

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a Facebook App that has a FancyBox (lightbox). The `iframe` is very long, and when you click an image, the lightbox shows at the middle of the `iframe` instead of the middle of the screen.

How do I get the amount of pixels that the browser has scrolled down?

/Kenneth B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it my self:

```
$(window.top).scrollTop();
```

If it is not within an iFrame use:

```
$(window).scrollTop();
```